# Doing memcpy without allocating memory with malloc before

Tags: c, memcpy, dlopen

I am asking myself why this piece of code works well when I haven't allocated memory for fptr. I would expect that it has rather an **Undefined Behavior** because of doing memcpy without allocating memory for fptr or?

```
struct conf *pconf = NULL; 
void (*fptr)(char *, struct conf **);
void *temp = dlsym(dlptr, "config_run_all"); 
memcpy(&fptr, &temp, sizeof fptr); 
fptr("test.conf", &pconf);
```

Comment: I am confused by the question; why do you say you haven't allocated memory for `fptr`? It's a variable; it is by definition a storage location.

Comment: This is undefined behaviour, just not for the reason you think it is. If I recall correctly, a void pointer is allowed to be larger than a function pointer and therefore you might not be copying the right bits into `fptr`.

Comment: @EricLippert Unfortunately, using the POSIX function `dlsym` requires you to use behavior that is undefined according the C standard. But casting is better than `memcpy`.

Answer (score 3):

You have allocated memory for `fptr`:

```
void (*fptr)(char *, struct conf **);`
```

This declares `fptr` as a pointer to function.

The `memcpy()` assigns the value from `temp` into `fptr`, making it so that `fptr` points to the function that `temp` points to.

What would be problematic would be omitting the `&` from the `memcpy()`; then you'd be trying to copy to memory when `fptr` has not been set to point to anything.

Comment: What about the fact that he's copying a `void *` into a function pointer? I think it's problematic since these pointer types are not necessarily the same size.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves: We had the same thought at the same time; see the comments above.

Comment: @EricLippert yea, I just read it. And then I saw interjay's comment, which kind of explains the rationale behind the code. But still, I'd prefer to cast.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves: The situation is complicated as POSIX 2013 removed the explicit guarantee that pointers to functions and pointers to objects have the same size. As I understand it, they've added the burden to the `dlsym()` function. I have documentation on it, but I've not yet assimilated it. Some pointers: _Change Number: XSH/TC1/D5/0017 [74]
[...] Section: 2.12.3 Pointer Types
Delete Section 2.12.3:
[...]
Rationale: Austin Group Defect Report(s) applied: 74.
See http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=74
The full text of TC1 [as] document U130 at http://www.opengroup.org/bookstore_

Answer (score 2):

Your code is basically equivalent to:

```
struct conf *pconf = NULL; 
void (*fptr)(char *, struct conf **) = (void (*)(char*, struct conf**)) dlsym(dlptr, "config_run_all"); 
fptr("test.conf", &pconf);
```

witout `temp`.

Answer (score 2):

The clue is in the memcpy invocation.

```
memcpy(&fptr, &temp, sizeof fptr);
```

You are copying to the address of the pointer, not dereferencing it. This is overwriting the memory of the pointer variable itself, not what it points to (which is nothing).